# Unable to load MP3 from same domain in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security

I have an issue with a Flash applet that I've written; it's an MP3 player that is supposed to load an MP3 file from a web address.

When I run the SWF on my local computer, it works like a charm. However, when I put it on a webpage, it does not load the MP3 file. (I guess that's what I get for not testing it that way beforehand.) I've double-checked permissions and it seems that everything is as it should be.

I know that AS3 has some cross-domain policies, but I'm loading the MP3 file from the same domain. I understand that Flash has sandbox properties, but I would expect that a file in the same domain shouldn't be a problem. I've heard of people having problems with SWFs before, but not regular media files.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? I doubt I'm the first to experience this. If possible, I'd like find a solution that doesn't require rewriting the code, as I have a release version of the SWF on my site currently. (Rewriting won't be a problem, but I have to wait until the end of the day to do it, and the SWF is on display now.)

Edit:

I had three friends test this, and it worked for them. However, it still didn't work for me. I'm at home now, and I'm testing - my applet loads an MP3 in Firefox, but not in Chrome. (Oddly, the friends who tested were using Chrome, which loaded it with no issues.) At work, my applet would not load an MP3 in Chrome or Firefox.

I can't figure out the sporadic behavior. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: *Hello all* is constantly cut off because greetings and closings are discouraged at SO. This is a Q&A site, not a bulletin board.

Comment: Set up a listener for the mp3 loader and trace any error message to a dynamic textfield on the stage. That might give you some clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Or try checking for a 404 error when trying to load the MP3 file, for example using Firebug or the Activity log in Safari or Developer Tools in Chrome or similar tool. Installing the debug version of Flash Player may also give some info, it displays errors for stuff that fails silently in the regular Flash Player: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: @crooksy88 Both good suggestions - I was planning on doing that, but I can only do that when I get home. (I'm currently at work, on a computer that isn't mine - it doesn't have any Flash authoring tools.) I was wondering if anyone had run into this problem before and would be able to recognize it.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö I've checked, and the file does exist (and the permissions are correct). My work computer, unfortunately, does not have the debug player, so I'll have to wait until I get home to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the MP3 file will be relative to the HTML page (not the SWF), so it could be that the path is wrong.

Comment: I'm using an absolute path - a full url: http://www.domain.com/directory/song.mp3, unfortunately. I did try a relative path to see if that would work, but I may have had it wrong.

Comment: With absolute paths, keep in mind that http:// domain.com and http:// www. domain.com are considered different domains and can raise security problems without a crossdomain policy file.